# Multiple node inserts for an XML column in TSQL

Tags: xml, t-sql, sqlxml

I have an XML valued column that has multiple "parent" nodes. I need to insert a "child" node into each parent node. If I use

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn.modify('insert <child/> into (//parent)[1]')
```

, then I'm inserting a child node into the first parent only.

How do I insert a child in every parent with a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the easiest way to accomplish this is to reconstruct the XML with a SELECT statement using CROSS APPLY and FOR XML.

Here's an example, hope it makes sense.  With this approach, you could also JOIN to another table for the data you want to insert into the `<child2 />` node making this solution quite flexible.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( Document XML )
INSERT INTO @t
SELECT '<root><parent><child1>first row data</child1></parent><parent><child1>second row data</child1></parent></root>'

SELECT
    ref.value('child1[1]', 'varchar(max)') as child1, 
    'something to insert' as child2
FROM @t CROSS APPLY Document.nodes('//parent') R(ref)
FOR XML PATH('parent'), ROOT('root')
```

> Results

```
<root>
  <parent>
    <child1>first row data</child1>
    <child2>something to insert</child2>
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <child1>second row data</child1>
    <child2>something to insert</child2>
  </parent>
</root>
```

Comment: @ulu - I'll try to post an example of cross apply when I have time later today, but check out this post - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlxml/thread/4d0cd921-eab9-4b3e-b210-52b6ee65f6c1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need something more complicated, I need to add a child node after similar child nodes, so a replace won't work. Would be great to look at your cross apply example though.

Comment: @ulu - sorry for the delayed response, had a lot going on.  I've updated my solution using CROSS APPY and FOR XML to perform the 'insert' and basically rebuild the XML with the new node.

Answer (score 0):

I ended moving one level up (i.e. taking all parent nodes), calculating the replaced XML, and using "replace value of" instead of "insert"